# Laravel 5.4 2 tables in collection in foreach

Tags: php, laravel-5

Ok so I have setup a table to manage two different tables (images and videos). So I'm trying to show a list of content like a feed. But each table has a different style. Now I managed to pull through relationships each table. But displaying them has been my problem.

```
 $content = Content::orderBy('updated_at')
->with('usersVideos','usersVideos', 'usersImages')->get();
```

now in the blade when I try to display it using this I only get one table.

this is for pulling from the image table

```
 @foreach($activities  as $a => $activity)

    @if($activity->usersImages)
        @foreach($activity->usersImages as $image)
            //display image

        @endforeach
    @elseif($activity->usersVideos)
        @foreach($activity->usersVideos)
            //display videos
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

Not sure if there is a better way to pull from the tables into the same feed. Any suggestions

Comment: what are you doing with `$content`? Where does `$activities` come from? And you also use with 'usersVideos' twice. Also, for the future, please try format the code a little better, so it is easier for us to help.

Comment: I'll edit it...content is a model for the contetn table

Comment: Is use the content table id to manage the content on the video table and the image table using "content_id".